# Testing private SaaS on EC2?

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, saas

I would like to start doing some testing of our SaaS application on our EC2 instance and had some questions on how to test this outside of our local dev environment.

What are some of my options on making this private within EC2 to fully test the wildcard subdomains without making the site live?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VPN to make EC2 subnet as part of your private network,Refer amazon document. Then a local DNS maybe needed to map wildcard subdomains or simple edit your host file.

Another suggestion is to only open service to your office's ip , redirect request from other IP to 404 etc.